# Set text of StyleClassedTextArea programmatically

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, richtextfx

The RichTextFX library has a nice StyleClassedTextArea which fits my use case nicely.

However, I can't find a way of programmatically setting the text on it - I can get it fine, and type, but can't find any way of altering it.

I presume there's something big I'm missing but can't quite work it out! Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replaceText(start, end, text)` method. If `start==end` this will work as an insert; if `start==end==getLength()` as an append, if `text.equals("")` as a delete, etc.